# The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this function to count with day names, and when I am add a long date he give this error

> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Can someone please help?

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST
    (@d1 DATE, 
     @d2 DATE, 
     @nd VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        (WITH AllDates AS
         (
             SELECT @d1 AS DateOf
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD (DAY, 1, DateOf)
             FROM AllDates
             WHERE DateOf < @d2
         ) 
         SELECT COUNT(*) SumOfDays 
         FROM AllDates 
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM STRING_SPLIT (@nd,' ') 
                       WHERE DATENAME(weekday, dateof) = value)
        )
```

Comment: I don't think it's permitted to name a function COUNT.  It's a reserved word

Comment: @taiielmehdi What `@d1, @d2, @nd` values did you supply to the query?

Comment: @taii-el-mehdi Please post some data that you used for input parameters.

Comment: @JeffModen SELECT * FROM [dbo].[COUNT]('2022-06-06','2029-08-08','Monday Tuesday')

Comment: @SteveC i am using another name but without any success :)

Comment: As for the recursion error, you need to set max recursion in the query that's calling the function.  If poor CPU performance and a totally unnecessary number of reads don't deter you from using incremental recursive CTEs, this reason alone should.  Please see the following answer on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232

Comment: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[COUNT_dt]('2022-06-06','2029-08-08','Monday Tuesday') return 750.  My function appears to be working properly

Comment: @taii-el-mehdi So post what YOUR using!

Comment: I changed the name of the function to Count_dt instead of Count.  It's not good use to name a function with a reserved literal so I added _dt to the name

Comment: @SteveC i am try but she give me this error "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: @SteveC Is Just a fake name

Comment: With the method I'm suggesting there is no maximum recursion.  The tally function will completely fill a UNIQUE BIGINT

Comment: Like I said, you need to add the MAXRECURSION option to your outer query. 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[COUNT]('2022-06-06','2029-08-08','Monday Tuesday')
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add `option (maxrecursion 0)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) SumOfDays 
FROM AllDates 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nd,' ') 
              WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dateof) = value
             )
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: @taiielmehdi . . . That is not a helpful comment.  You should specify what the error is.

Comment: The error was probably because you used the "AllDates" table, which the OP probably doesn't have.  Please post how to construct your "AllDates" table.

Comment: @JeffModen . . . `AllDates` is the CTE that the OP has defined.  I didn't include that in the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Interesting.  That may be what the OP didn't understand either.  I do, however, agree that this OP really needs to get in the habit of posting what error they got.  Thanks for the feedback, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function doesn't reference any physical tables it's good to specify 'with schemabinding' when defining the function.  This allows the optimizer to skip late binding to objects.  Here's the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST
    (@d1 DATE, 
     @d2 DATE, 
     @nd VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE with schemabinding
AS
    RETURN
        (WITH AllDates AS
         (
             SELECT @d1 AS DateOf
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD (DAY, 1, DateOf)
             FROM AllDates
             WHERE DateOf < @d2
         ) 
         SELECT COUNT(*) SumOfDays 
         FROM AllDates 
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM STRING_SPLIT (@nd,' ') 
                       WHERE DATENAME(weekday, dateof) = value)
        )
```

Query to execute

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[TEST]('2022-06-06','2029-08-08','Monday Tuesday') 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output

```
SumOfDays
750
```

Below is a different approach using a tally function

---

**Tally based approach**

One way to go would be to drop the recursive cte altogether and go with a "tally" table approach.  Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232) for more details.

Something like this

Inline table valued function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
    Jeff Moden Script on SSC: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

Query

```
CREATE FUNCTION COUNT_Dt(@d1 DATE, @d2 DATE, @nd VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE with schemabinding
AS
RETURN
select COUNT(*) SumOfDays 
FROM dbo.fnTally(0, datediff(d, @d1, @d2)) fn
        cross apply
        (select dateadd(d, fn.n, @d1) dt) da
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM STRING_SPLIT(@nd,' ') 
             WHERE DATENAME(weekday,da.dt)=[value]);
go
```

Comment: Ok... same question for you... what parameters did you use to test with?

Comment: '2000101' is a Wednesday.  Select * from COUNT_dt('20200101', '20200105', 'this that Wednesday the other') returns a count of 1.

Comment: @SteveC thank you please it possible to add OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) inside my function

Comment: It's not possible.   The OPTION must be added to the statement which references the tvf containing the rCTE

Comment: @SteveC i do but she give me error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'option'.'

Comment: Hey bro, where's my points?  You've been provided more then enough information to make an informed decision.